# Cannot import name 'update_default_config' from 'astropy.config.configuration'

Tags: python, config, astropy, aplpy

When I imported aplpy,
I got this error:
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [12], in <cell line: 9>()
7 from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
8 import astropy.units as u
----> 9 import aplpy as ap
10 from glob import glob
11 import astropy.units as u

```
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aplpy/__init__.py:9, in <module>
      2 """
      3 APLpy : Astronomical Plotting Library in Python
      4 """
      6 # Affiliated packages may add whatever they like to this file, but
      7 # should keep this content at the top.
      8 # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
----> 9 from ._astropy_init import *  # noqa
     10 # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     12 if not _ASTROPY_SETUP_:  # noqa

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aplpy/_astropy_init.py:21, in <module>
     19 import os
     20 from warnings import warn
---> 21 from astropy.config.configuration import (
     22     update_default_config,
     23     ConfigurationDefaultMissingError,
     24     ConfigurationDefaultMissingWarning)
     26 # Create the test function for self test
     27 from astropy.tests.runner import TestRunner

ImportError: cannot import name 'update_default_config' from 'astropy.config.configuration' (/Users/zly/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/config/configuration.py)`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like astropy removed that function.

https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/changelog.html#id1

Comment: So I should install an older version of astropy?

Comment: I installed  version 5.3 of astropy, but it didn't work.

Comment: @laklak The error happens inside the spectral-cube package.  So it seems you are using a version of the spectral-cube package which does not know that the `update_default_config` function has been removed from the astropy package.  What version of spectral-cube do you have installed?

Comment: The version of spectral-cube is 0.2.1.
And when I imported apply (2.1.0), I got the same error.

Comment: The latest version of spectral-cube is 0.6.5.  Why are you using such an old version?

Comment: I don't know. Ok, thank you very much, I will have a try.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. The version of my spectral-cube is 0.6.5.

Comment: @laklak Please update your question to include the full error message traceback, not just the final line.

Comment: I updated my question based on your suggestion.

Comment: @laklak Oh, the error is actually in `radio-beam`, not `sepctral-cube`.  What version of `radio-beam` do you have installed?

Comment: The version of radio-beam is (0.3.4).

Comment: The latest `radio-beam` is 0.3.7, maybe it fixes this issue.

Comment: I updated radio-beam package to 0.3.7. No more errors. 
But I still have the same error when I imported aplpy. The version of aplpy is (2.1.0). I updated my question with the full description of apply. Can you help me ？

Comment: The `aplpy` module has not been updated in nearly two years.  I wonder if it has been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, after reading the thread at https://github.com/aplpy/aplpy/issues/492#issuecomment-1922601132, I tried:

```
conda uninstall aplpy
conda uninstall astropy # might be already uninstalled by aplpy
conda install astropy==5.3.4
conda install aplpy
```

And it worked for me. Hope this helps!